# EF5 update disconnected graph (n-tier) one-to-many

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5, one-to-many, n-tier-architecture

**Problem:** *insert / update entity related to a parent with a one-to-many relationship in a disconnected graph scenario*.

**UPDATE**

I found that the problem is just with new UserProfile I add to Brewery, the first insert is done successfully (= EF sees the relationship and creates the correct insert statement)

```
exec sp_executesql N'insert [dbo].[BreweryUserProfiles]([BreweryId], [UserId])
values (@0, @1)
',N'@0 int,@1 int',@0=12,@1=3
```

No way till now to have the update working.

**---**

The parent entity (Brewery) has a one-to-one relation with Rank, and a one-to-many relation with UserProfile. I used a join table for this second relation. I'm able to insert / update the Rank when I insert / update the parent brewery (even if I had to add some code, EF wasn't able to keep the relationship). I'm not able to insert / update an user profile

**Reference**: I'm using a generic repository + a dbcontextextension as described here: http://www.martinwilley.com/net/code/data/genericrepository.html

**DB diagram**

[image]

**POCO**

```
  [Table("Breweries")]
  public class Brewery : ABrewery
  {
    //PK
    public int BreweryId { get; set; }

    //FK
    public int RankId { get; set; }

    ...

    //Navigation
    public virtual ICollection<BrewMaster> BrewMasters { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }
    public virtual Country Country { get; set; }
    public virtual Rank Rank { get; set; }
  }

  public class Rank : IRank
  {
    public int RankId { get; set; }
    public int TotalHits { get; set; }
    public decimal Value { get; set; }
  }

[Table("UserProfiles")]
public class UserProfile : IUserProfile
{
  [Key]
  public int UserId { get; set; }
  public string UserName { get; set; }

  ...

  //Navigation
  public virtual List<Email> Emails { get; set; }
  public virtual List<Social> Socials { get; set; }
  public virtual List<Telephone> Telephones { get; set; }
  public virtual Country Country { get; set; }
}
```

**Entity (Brewery) Configuration**

```
  HasMany(e => e.UserProfiles)
    .WithMany()
    .Map(m =>
    {
      m.MapLeftKey("BreweryId");
      m.MapRightKey("UserId");
      m.ToTable("BreweryUserProfiles");
    });

  Property(e => e.RankId)
    .IsRequired();
```

**Solution tried**

To insert / update Rank, was enough to do that

```
public void AddOrUpdate(Brewery entity)
{
  entity.RankId = entity.Rank.RankId;

  _context.AddOrUpdate<Rank>(entity.Rank); //add or update is a dbcontextextension, 
                                           //basically just Add or 
                                           //Attach + change entity status

  _repository.AddOrUpdate(entity);
```

To update the BreweryUserProfiles I tried to:

```
  if (entity.UserProfiles.Count > 0)
  {
    entity.UserProfiles = new List<UserProfile>();
    foreach (var user in entity.UserProfiles)
    {
      entity.UserProfiles.Add(GetUserProfile(user.UserId)); //get userprofile from db
    }
  }

  _repository.AddOrUpdate(entity);
```

or

```
  if (entity.UserProfiles.Count > 0)
  {
    entity.UserProfiles = new List<UserProfile>();
    foreach (var user in entity.UserProfiles)
    {
      _context.AddOrUpdate<UserProfile>(this.GetUserProfile(user.UserId)); //that basically is the same
    }
  }
```

when I tried to do the same for the UserProfile, obviously EF executed an insert / update on UserProfile table (useless .. I need to update BreweryUserProfiles table).
If I understood correctly, the Rank is working 'cause I have a FK in Brewery.RankId property, while I don't have (and don't want) a two way navigation between Brewery and UserProfile

I hope my problem is clear, I trid to paste all relevant code, but if needed I can provide more informations. Thanks in advance

Comment: In the code snippets after _To update the BreweryUserProfiles_ I assume `entity` is a `Brewery`, but what is its state? Is it attached, Added, Modified, Unchanged? I think the problem is that you replace its `UserProfiles` collection.

Comment: Yes, is a Brewery, in Detached status. I updated the code, the entity will be attached (then in Modified status) the line right after (_repository.AddOrUpdate(entity);). Due to the disconnected scenario, the entity to which I replace the collection is just an object not mapped by EF yet