# EF5 Many To Many update disconnected scenario

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, many-to-many, entity-framework-5

I didn't find yet a good solution to this problem (similar ticket here [EF5 update disconnected graph (n-tier) one-to-many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15050480/ef5-update-disconnected-graph-n-tier-one-to-many)).

I found and followed this example: http://entityframeworktutorial.net/update-many-to-many-entities-in-entity-framework.aspx#.UTBeTDBhif8.

This works just fine, but it creates a duplicate of the related entities (with sql profiler I saw the Insert into RelatedEntities .. I would expected just an insert / update on the MyEntities_Related join table and I don't understand why EF makes an insert on the RelatedEntities table :(

And here is my code:

```
public void AddOrUpdate(MyEntity entity) {
    var dbEntity = _context.MyEntities
      .Include(e => e.RelatedEntitis)
      .Where(e => e.ID == entity.ID)
      .SingleOrDefault();

    var newRelated = entity.RelatedEntitis.ToList<RelatedEntity>();
    var dbRelated = dbEntity.RelatedEntity.ToList<RelatedEntity>();

    _context.Entry(dbEntity).CurrentValues.SetValues(entity);

    var comparer = new EqualityComparer();
    var addedRelated = newRelated.Except(dbRelated, comparer).ToList<RelatedEntity>();
    var deletedRelated = dbRelated.Except(newRelated, comparer).ToList<RelatedEntity>();

    addedRelated.ForEach(e => dbEntity.RelatedEntity.Add(e));
    deletedRelated.ForEach(e => dbEntity.RelatedEntity.Remove(e));
}

public class EqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<RelatedEntity>
{
    public int GetHashCode(RelatedEntity obj)
    {
      return (obj == null) ? 0 : obj.ID.GetHashCode();
    }

    public bool Equals(RelatedEntity x, RelatedEntity y)
    {
      if (ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;
      if (x == null || y == null) return false;
      return x.ID == y.ID;
    }
}
```

the db schema is like the following:

```
|------------------|
| Table MyEntities |
|------------------| 
| int ID //PK      |
|------------------| 


|--------------------------|
| Table MyEntities_Related |
|--------------------------|
| int MyEntityID           |
| int RelatedID            | 
|--------------------------|


|-----------------------|
| Table RelatedEntities |
|-----------------------|
| int RelatedID //PK    |
| string Name           | 
|-----------------------|
```

any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Probably I have unserstand .. the entity that I'm trying to update is detached and the related as well, so EF isn't able to understand that my related are already existing and insert them twice. If I load the related seems to work as I expected. I'll copy paste my solution as soon as Ill be sure it's working correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**SOLUTION**
I don't know if it's the best, but it works for me and I think it has sense. EF creates a duplicate of the relatedentities because they were detached,
I changed my code in this way:

```
public void AddOrUpdate(MyEntity entity) {
    var dbEntity = _context.MyEntities
      .Include(e => e.RelatedEntitis)
      .Where(e => e.ID == entity.ID)
      .SingleOrDefault();

    //replace entities with those taken from the context
    var relatedEntities = _context.RelatedEntities;
    var detachedEntities = entity.RelatedEntities;
    entity.RelatedEntities = new List<RelatedEntity>();
    foreach (var ent in detachedEntities)
    {
      entity.RelatedEntities.Add(relatedEntities .Where(e => e.ID == hop.ID).SingleOrDefault());
    }

    var newRelated = entity.RelatedEntitis.ToList<RelatedEntity>();
    var dbRelated = dbEntity.RelatedEntity.ToList<RelatedEntity>();

    _context.Entry(dbEntity).CurrentValues.SetValues(entity);
    _context.Entry(dbEntity.RelatedEntity).CurrentValues.SetValues(entity.RelatedEntitis);

    var comparer = new EqualityComparer();
    var addedRelated = newRelated.Except(dbRelated, comparer).ToList<RelatedEntity>();
    var deletedRelated = dbRelated.Except(newRelated, comparer).ToList<RelatedEntity>();

    addedRelated.ForEach(e => dbEntity.RelatedEntity.Add(e));
    deletedRelated.ForEach(e => dbEntity.RelatedEntity.Remove(e));
}
```

Comment: _context.Entry(dbRelatedEntities).CurrentValues.SetValues(RelatedEntities); is missing. If it added I'll upvote it.

Comment: Here is a similar question on stackoverflow on how to code a generic version http://goo.gl/2sCky